# Is it safe to use the output string if `snprintf()` failed?

Tags: c

According to man, `snprintf` can return negative value if fails. But is it safe to use the output buffer string after `snprintf` failed? By "safe" I mean it's null-terminated inside the buffer.

Comment: If `snprintf()` had created a string it wouldn't have failed...

Comment: @AndrewHenle: It could place `\0` before returning a negative value, for example. I would do that (just in case), but not sure about the standard and common implementations.

Answer (score 2):

No, AFAIR, there's no any guarantee.

```
int snprintf(char *restrict s, size_t n, const char *restrict format, ...);
```

> Unless either `n` is zero or the return code is negative, the output is
> null-terminated. **The output has been completely written if and only if
> the returned value is both nonnegative and less than `n`.** [Source](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2571.htm)